# iOS 14 Medium Widget Size Background Image Refuses to Fill

Tags: swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

For some reason I'm unable to get an image background to aspectFill correctly in XCode Version 12.0, but only on the `.systemMedium` widget size. It seems to work perfectly on the small and large sizes.

I've got a pretty simple View:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0.0, *)
struct Banana: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Spacer()
            Text("Aardvark Exactlywhat")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .shadow(
                    color: Color.black,
                    radius: 1.0,
                    x: CGFloat(4),
                    y: CGFloat(4))
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .background(
            Image("bananas")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        ).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0.0, *)
struct Banana_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Banana()
    }
}
```

And a pretty simple widget:

```
struct fruitWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Banana()
    }
}

@main
struct fruitWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "fruitWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            fruitWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("fruit Widget")
        .description("Enhance your day with delicious fruit.")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge])
    }
}

struct fruitWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group{
            fruitWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
                .previewContext(
                    WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
            fruitWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
                .previewContext(
                    WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
            fruitWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
                .previewContext(
                    WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemLarge))
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the aspect ratio, using GeometryReader and frame(), and a dozen other variations. Regardless of what I try, I get white space on the left and right in the medium widget. It only works for the large and small size. See image:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is fixed variant - as image in the background you have to expand `VStack` to full screen.

*Note: `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` allows to go beyond safe area when content is wider, but not make content wide.*

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading){
        Spacer()
        Text("Aardvark Exactlywhat")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .bold()
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .padding(.leading, 20)
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .shadow(
                color: Color.black,
                radius: 1.0,
                x: CGFloat(4),
                y: CGFloat(4))
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)   // << this one !!
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .background(
        Image("plant")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
    )
}
```