# Medium Widget Size Background Image or Color not filling the entire space

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

When trying to create a widget with minimal IOS 14, the background color or image refuses to fill the widget on the sides.
It works with containerBackground Modifier, but it's for IOS 17 or newer.
I also saw the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64019316/ios-14-medium-widget-size-background-image-refuses-to-fill), but the answer from there now working for some reason, even if I copy the exact same code:
[image]

```
struct WidgetEntryView : View {
var entry: SomeEntry
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Spacer()
        Text("Aardvark Exactlywhat")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .bold()
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .padding(.leading, 20)
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .shadow(
                color: Color.black,
                radius: 1.0,
                x: CGFloat(4),
                y: CGFloat(4))
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)   // << this one !!
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .background(
        backgroundImage()
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
    )
}
```

Comment: On which iOS version are you testing this?

Comment: @Timmy on IOS 17, and I see what you saying, I will try to run it on earlier versions

Comment: @Timmy yes, in IOS 16 it worked, thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a wrapper function that uses `.containerBackground` when available and falls back to using `.background` when needed:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func widgetBackground<T: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> T) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            containerBackground(for: .widget, content: content)
        }else {
            background(content())
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
.widgetBackground {
    backgroundImage()
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to add negative horizontal padding to the image.

I measured the gap to be 16pt, but if the image is just a space filler and it doesn't matter if there is generous overflow then you could make it bigger as a precaution.

```swift
.background(
    backgroundImage()
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .padding(.horizontal, -16)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped, but I just figured out that the issue is, that in the earlier version of IOS everything worked just fine, but starting with IOS 17, you should use .containerBackground